# SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'dbuser' on .NET 6 WebAPI Hosted on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have deployed a *.NET* 6 WebApi on *Azure*, but it throws Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'dbuser' exception **but the same WebApi works fine when hosted on a different server**. I'm using the same *ConnectionString* in *appsettings.json* and the database server is on *Azure*. I have run out of ideas to fix this because it works fine in a different hosting environment and I have used an App Service to create a deployment container in Azure. I deployed it using Visual Studio 2022.

Exception details can be accessed [here](https://cutfs-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/amhlaba_cut_ac_za/EamlUSdBxI1HoMKS8lzplVUB7yzmQ8TTCsQxP3lJY2E32g?e=CEiz18)

**Failing Azure WebApi**

[image: Failing Azure WebApi]

**Working WebApi on Experimental Server**

[image: Working Server Sample]

Comment: There are two ways of a server connecting to the database 1) Forward the client user credentials to the database 2) User a unique server credentials.  I need to know which method is being used.  Method 1 passes uses the client Role.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng I'm using Method 1, the confusion is emanating from the fact that Azure is refusing credentials of a database in Azure. The other server is connecting well to the same database using the same connectionstring.

Comment: The server need to verify the users credential by going to a password server.  So something is wrong with the domain or nameserver.

Comment: @jdweng I have used database server credentials in the connectionString and it does not work on Azure deployment: Server=tcp:dbServerName.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=dbNamep;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=dbUser;Password={dbPassword};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;

Comment: I would open a cmd.exe on working and non working system and compare results from >IPConfig/all

Comment: @jdweng Thank you, I will continue troubleshooting and update this post once I get a working solution.

Comment: If you can login to the server with same credentials than the servers are good and I would start looking at the client.  You can type from START cmd.exe and then right click shortcut and select "RUNAS Admin". These metes refrecrsh the credentials between the clients and the nameservers.

Comment: Is everybody using same SQL Server?  UserName/Password is often blocks and you have to use Integrated connection which uses same password server as clients and servers.  The error message seem to indicate the client server connection is good.  So problem may be in client and database credentials not working.  Make sure the database on the SQL Server is using Windows Credentials and not a SQL credentials.  You can use SQL Sever Management Studio to connect to database from client and see if the clients credentials work at database.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I cannot tell exactly what the issue was but doing the following helped.

1. I deleted my App Service in Azure
2. I deleted my Publish/Deployment Profile In Visual Studio
3. I recreated my App Service Using Visual Studio Azure Deployment Option
4. I updated my App Service .Net Version from .Net 5 to .NET 6 under Stack Settings
5. I did not configure SQL Server Database Service Dependencies, this will force the app to read the preconfigured *ConnectionString* in *appsettings.json*
6. I published the app and it worked this time around.